# Change Datepicker Format and Output based on Form Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

apologies in advance if this question's already been answered. I searched but couldn't find an answer.

I use datepicker on a webpage with the code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"DD, MM d, yy",
    minDate: 0,
  });
});
```

I also have the following form.

```html
<select id="language">
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="french">French</option> 
</select>
<button onclick="showDate()">Submit</button>
```

I would like to change the datepicker format and `dayNames` values based on the option selected. I believe I need an `if` operator for this, but can't seem to get it working properly.

So, if the option "french" were selected, the dateFormat would be "DD d MM yy" and the dayNames would be set as `"dayNames: ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"]"`.

The date generated would then appear in a paragraph. So if French were selected the date would read `"mercredi 25 décembre 2019"` and if English were selected the date would read `"Wednesday, December 25, 2019"` due to the default date format.

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery and would appreciate any insight with this. I originally thought about changing the localization of the calendar upon selection of "french", but that may overcomplicate things.

Comment: Which datepicker widget are you using?   Looks like maybe the Bootstrap datepicker?  (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and not the jQuery UI datepicker, or any others?  And are you wanting the datepicker itself to change language?  Or just the result when you click the submit button?

Comment: Hi @ReverendPete, I believe I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker as I modified the code from these sources: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_datepicker.htm. 

I'd just like the result when you click the submit button; the datepicker itself can remain in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification!  Here's an answer that should help you with what you're looking for.  All the major browsers can translate dates with javascript, using `.toLocaleDateString(language, options)`, so I have written you a snippet to run that you can play around with.

Note:  I have changed your select to have values that are the locale strings required for the toLocaleDateString function, and you can play around with the formatting with the `dateOptions` object.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

So the `getDate` method for the datepicker returns a javascript `Date` object, which is what is needed for `toLocaleDateString`.  And the `currentLanguage` variable is set using jquery to get the value of the selected dropdown item.

Hope this helps!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat:"DD, MM d, yy",
    minDate: 0,
  });
});

function showDate() {
  var dateOptions = { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
  var selectedDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
  var currentLanguage = $("#language option:selected").val();
  alert(selectedDate.toLocaleDateString(currentLanguage, dateOptions)); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<input id="datepicker">

<select id="language">
  <option value="en-US">English</option>
  <option value="fr-FR">French</option> 
</select>
<button onclick="showDate()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Reverend Pete! I appreciate the example and explanation, which solves my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, Sean.  Don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer so that it doesn't still show as unsolved...